# Accessing a hosted Python Script via Android application using Java

Tags: python, php, android

I'm trying to upgrade an old Android Calculator project (Math911 on the Google Play Store) and add some AI to handle user Math word problems.

For the AI component I want to follow the set-up provided in the following link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-math-application-with-langchain-agents-23919d09a4d3

I have experience using PHP composer and Packagist when installing packages on a PHP project. However, the link requires Conda which helps in setting up an environment and installing the packages needed.

I want to use Netbeans and a Python plugin in order to set up a development environment. My computer has Python installed already, so I should be able to compile it inside my Netbeans environment.

**Is it possible to install all the packages required for the project within the folders of my Netbeans Python project? Or should I exclusively use Conda as the link says?**

In the past, I have uploaded files from my PHP projects using Netbeans into my website hosting service. **How would I be able to upload the Python scripts into my website File structure?**

My goal is to use my Android Calculator application to communicate via the hosted website file and receive responses via a GET command. I have done this using PHP and the Android Volley SDK.
**What is the best set up to receive responses from the this 'hosted' Python Script using my Android Application?**

Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Seems like you are bit in over your head. Why not just get started and see how it shapes up? Then follow up with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Once I figure out how to upload the python scripts to my hosted website file structure, it should be straightforward! I think I will need to install Conda since is a Python package installer just like Composer is for PHP projects!